# How to write a number (int, double) to file using file descriptor in C?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int out_fd = open("file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);

    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    char tmp[12]={0x0};
    sprintf(tmp,"%11d", i);

    write(out_fd, tmp, sizeof(tmp));

    close(out_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

but it writes some trash to my file:

[image]

is there any good way to write a number (float, int, double) to file using file descriptor and write? Thanks

**thanks guys, solved:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int out_fd = open("plik.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);

    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    char tmp[1]={0x0};
    sprintf(tmp,"%d", i);

    write(out_fd, tmp, strlen(tmp));

    close(out_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(tmp)` return 12 but not 11. That's why you get null-character in your file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace `sizeof()` with `strlen()` to get the actual length of the string to write. e.g: 
`write(out_fd, tmp,strlen(tmp));`